# How to check the version of custom npm modules?

Tags: typescript-playground

I create a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKFEljgG9EIBXGJAGidaQGFdIAdkgEwACjjABnOAF842XASLoYAWhzcoqgCa4yVKsBFIomdEkRJJMFMygoR4iFLhIAHmwHbpCFmz7gEEKOEpIAPIzA2gBccNZQRgDmsgB8DFRwcMySJrEOAJ4UlDJUaEHWlta29iJwALxwABRgobHIVXYOYqEAlPVp9BlwZQIVKPVwLc6SAHQgKDBoABYzYCj2ILNRRZkjFQBGE1NSM9kmO3BEMHYCcGHawABuKe02nSJhAPQPz1QllKVyvAAIJgMATRp9OoDIZ7eBnKATegyC5XG5NIaZMK+biYzKTBZLOoAIk+RA6NRgkk+0SixLxmSIXhMdXozV6-Tur2qXQYM35x0kcgRrIRck+KX++LgEqGPSKKKAA) with custom npm modules in **Plugins** panel right side. But there is no version information for these npm modules. Where can I find the version information? Can I add a custom npm module with a specific version?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it in the [help section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#handbook-4), you don't need to specify version in the plugin section as it will always bring the latest one:

> If you need more control over the version of the types which are imported into the Playground, you can append // types: npm_tag_or_version
>
> ```js
> import { xy } from "xyz" // types: beta
> ```

In my experience with you might need to remove any prefixes such as `^`/`~`, and might need to wait/reload the page a few times until it works.